# Flatpicker check in check out

Tags: javascript, flatpickr

I am trying one of the example given in flatpickr which is Check in check out.
The example is working fine but when I use same syntax in the local machine it is not working like check-out date is able to select the previous date of check-in date.

```
var check_in = document.getElementById("check_in_date").flatpickr({
    altInput: true,
    altFormat: "F j Y",
    minDate: new Date()
});
var check_out = document.getElementById("check_out_date").flatpickr({
    altInput: true,
    altFormat: "F j Y",
    minDate: new Date()
});

check_in.config.onChange = function(dateObj) {
    check_out.set("minDate", dateObj.fp_incr(1));
};
check_out.config.onChange = function(dateObj) {
    check_in.set("maxDate", dateObj.fp_incr(-1));
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is working

```js
check_in_date = flatpickr("#check_in_date", {
    onChange: function(selectedDates, dateStr, instance) {
        check_out_date.set('minDate', selectedDates[0]);
    }
});
    
check_out_date = flatpickr("#check_out_date", {});
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/flatpickr/4.6.11/flatpickr.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/flatpickr/4.6.11/flatpickr.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="check_in_date" name="checkin">
<input type="text" id="check_out_date" name="checkin">
```

Answer (score 0):

Additionally you can also use the Flatpickr Range Calendar. This way you only need to use one input field.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  const myFlatpickr = $('#myFlatpickr').flatpickr({
    mode: "range",
    altFormat: "F j Y",
    minDate: new Date()
  });

  $(document).on('click', '#myButton', function() {
    $("#myResponse").html(`<b>Date checkin:</b> ${myFlatpickr.selectedDates[0]} <br><b>Date checkout:</b> ${myFlatpickr.selectedDates[1]}`);
  });
});
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/flatpickr/4.6.11/flatpickr.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/flatpickr/4.6.11/flatpickr.min.js"></script>
<input id="myFlatpickr" style="width:170px;">

<button id="myButton">View dates</button>

<div id="myResponse"></div>
```

Comment: Actually the API I am using requires 2 date fields.
Anyway thank you for your help.